# Big WP_Query on MAMP

Tags: sql, wordpress, mamp

I'm running an install of WP (3.5.2) on MAMP. Some queries are outputting stuff the way they should (post count, last 5 posts etc) but one isn't. This is a query going through about 550 custom posts and displaying information. I've got `'posts_per_page' => '-1'` in the arguments array and I noticed when I change the value to 100 I do get output. The loop of the query goes through all the custom post types and for each post it gets about 10 meta values. On my live website this is all working as expected.

I'm not very skilled in server setups and MAMP so I was wondering if this has anything to do with MAMP (or MySQL) being limited to a certain amount of database requests or something?

Webserver: Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/0.9.8x DAV/2 PHP/5.4.10

Comment: I would advise increasing some of the php.ini configuration values to allocate more memory, etc to PHP/mySQL.  Often localhost stacks are not preconfigured to access as many resources as a typical webserver.

Comment: Thanks. I've found that the max_allowed_packet = 1M. Changed that to 1024M but still no luck so I'll look for php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

It was a memory problem like Ennui suggested. I did two things to resolve my issue:

**1:Changed max_allowed_packet to 1024M in MySQL** (see [here](http://contolini.com/2009/08/11/fixing-mysql-max_allowed_packet-error-in-mamp/))
Added --max_allowed_packet=1024M to /Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh and restarted MAMP

**2: Changed memory_limit in php.ini** (my method below or see [here](http://blog-en.mamp.info/2009/09/increase-php-memory-limit-with-mamp-pro.html))
Open /Applications/bin/php/php5.4.10/conf/php.ini, look for memory_limit and change it (for me it was 32M, changed it to 1024M) and restart MAMP. If your using another version of php, look in your php version folder instead of php5.4.10.

I don't know if memory_limit was the problem or if it was a combination of PHP and MySQL since only changing max_allowed_packet didn't resolve my issue, but the two steps above work!